# SG3525 Fixed output pulse (Without feed-back circuitry)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver

[image]im making CDI circuit in which capacitor charges upto 300v and then discharge through the IGBT connected . but when i ground the capacitor the output voltage ground as well which is obvious. to compensate the voltage drop across the output, SG3525 increase pulse width which further make the situation more critical, excessive load on the mosfet and transformer and could damage the input power supply  this is why i dont want to use feedback . i just need and adjustable duty cycle or fixed manually so i can reduce the power loss.(feedback circuit in the image is simple representation!!)[image]

Comment: Can you include LC values with pulse width, f?

Comment: Full schematic would help and quite possibly be needed.

Comment: im not sure about any LC value for Pulse width.

Comment: circuitry image is added

Comment: The symbol you have used for the 25N120 is the symbol for a MOSFET, not an IGBT.

Comment: yes i used but theres an IGBT . thats why i mentioned that particular name 25N120

Comment: The feedback you require is that the output voltage has reached the required level - the converter should shutdown. have  a RC network that delays the restart for a given time if the voltage drops below a threshold. The CDI circuits I’ve seen use a ‘ringing choke’ inverter that copes with the initial high current when the capacitor is discharged.

Comment: As well, the output of the bridge rectifier is backwards.

Comment: You need to define transformer parameters primary L and turns ratio

Comment: The ratio is 5P+5p / 90S

Comment: I have tried to add 2.2uf capacitor on the inv pin and ground so if voltage drops at output the feedback voltage stays same for some time. But trick didnt work